# ã— instead of x in vue-select

Tags: laravel, encoding, character-encoding, vuejs2

I'm using https://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/ in my Laravel application and in multiple selects, I see `A-` instead of `x`. 
I know it's a encoding issue, but I am not sure how to solve it. 
My encoding is `<meta charset="utf-8">`.
Any ideas? Thanks for help!

**Updated**

Also, I check Nginx charset and it's also set to `charset utf-8;`. All files are in encoding utf-8

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how but in my machine in vue-select sources in npm-modules it was set to "Ã—" instead of "x". But checking on GitHub sources of https://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/ it's "x". So after I reinstall vue-select it fix the issue